# How can I set default calendar to gregorian in the Whole project? Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

I want to set the calendar to default Gregorian in whole project.
Even user change the calendar in Device Settings. But I want the calendar to only show the gregorian. In my case I don't want to use this code.

```
NSCalendar *gregcalendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
[formatter setCalendar:gregcalendar];
```

I want to set the calendar default to gregorian without using it. Is there anything else to do it? Like as set the calendar in Info.plist or something else. Please suggest me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Use global variable with `static` or create singleton class to hold it

Comment: Can you show me with sample code please? Thanks for your patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Singleton class Or Create global varibale in appDelegate class like this:

Add In Header File of your AppDelegate:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSCalendar *gregorian;
```

Add In Implmenation file of your AppDelegate:

Use like this :

```
self.gregorian = [self calendar];

- (NSCalendar*)calendar
{
    if (self.gregorian == nil) {
        NSCalendar* temc = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

        NSLocale* usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"Add local code";

        self.gregorian = temc;
    }
    return gregorian;
}
```

Comment: yes it's worked but I have already existing project then this is not working.. Because I don't use that type variable....I think I need to use method swizzling or something else.

Comment: I don't use Singleton any global variable because project is already exist...so can you suggest otherway...@Rishi