# How to set calendar type to Gregorian when app launch?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Does anyone know how to set calendar type to Gregorian when the app is launch? Most of users of the app that I created use Buddhist calendar, but I want to change it to Gregorian so Datepicker in the app use Gregorian.

Here is the code that I put in app delegate.

```
if (self.gregorian == nil) {
    NSCalendar* temc = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    self.gregorian = temc;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your codes?

Comment: I do not have any Idea how to do it yet. But this is what I tried. I put this line of code in app delegate.

`if (self.gregorian == nil) {
        NSCalendar* temc = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
        self.gregorian = temc;
    }    if (self.gregorian == nil) {
        NSCalendar* temc = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
        self.gregorian = temc;
    }`

Comment: Please put the code in your question by editing it; codes in comment are very hard to read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set default calendar to gregorian in the Whole project? Objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601081/how-can-i-set-default-calendar-to-gregorian-in-the-whole-project-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to set the [`calendar`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/1615973-calendar) property of your date picker.

Something like:

```
self.datePicker.calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
```

or, if you have set your property,

```
self.datePicker.calendar = self.gregorian
```

There is no way to change the "default" calendar for your app so that date pickers implicitly use the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: I have set the property of the calendar. The calendar now appear in Gregorian format. However, it seem there is still something wrong with the date that make my search function does not work. But If I change the device calendar to Gregorian, it worked.

Comment: can i set globally. my app is old and I have big project.. and I have used calendar so many places.

Answer (score 0):

Set your datePicker's calendar to gregorian type.

`datePicker.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)`

Answer (score -1):

date picker by default is Gregorian

```
    var datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.calender = .gregorian
```